# How to check if SwiperJS is available for use on a page?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am using a single **custom.js** file in the footer for all of my websites pages.

In this **custom.js** there is the code that initializes the SwiperJS slider which is on the home page.

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".slider-1", {
    loop: true,
});
```

Now, I load the SwiperJS library on only the home page since it is only required there. But this results in the following error in the rest of the pages which don't have the script attached.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
```

The same also happens with the **GLightbox** library since I load it only on the gallery page but its initialization code is in the **custom.js** file.

How do I check if the library exists before running the initialization code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try-catch

```js
try {
  let swiper = new Swiper(".slider-1", {
    loop: true,
  });
}
catch (e) { /* console.log("no swiper") */ }
```

OR

```js
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider-1");
if (slider) {
  let swiper = new Swiper(".slider-1", {
    loop: true,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can the catch block be empty? I don't want to display any message in the console.

Comment: You can also test if the slider exists. See update

Answer (score 3):

```
if (typeof Swiper !== 'undefined') {
  /* DO STUFF */
}
```